# ASP.NET MVC: The required anti-forgery form field “__RequestVerificationToken” is not present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, antiforgerytoken

The following error occurs when building my code 
The required anti-forgery form field “__RequestVerificationToken” is not present

This is the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel1 model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int month = DateTime.ParseExact(model.BirthMonth.ToString(), "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
                DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(model.BirthYear, month, model.BirthDay);
                var user = new ApplicationUser { Email = model.Email, UserName = model.UserName, Name = model.Name, Surname = model.Surname, BirthDate = birthDate, Country = model.Country, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    db.Users.Add(user);

                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    var users = db.Users.ToList();
                    var adminUsers = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdmin == true).ToList();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
```

//VIEW

```
@model GAPT.Models.RegisterViewModel1
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tours-Maltin";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <form action="@Url.Action("Register","Account")" method="post">
                        @*"Index","Home"*@
                        <div class="form-group" style="width:280px">
                            @*<label for="name-login">Surname <p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name-login" required>*@
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="width:280px">
                            @*<label for="surname-login">Surname <p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname-register" required>*@
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @*<label for="email-login">Email <p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-login" required>*@
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <script>
                            </script>
                            <label for="dob-login" style="display:block;">Date of Birth <p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <select name="BirthDay" id="BirthDay" onchange="runDay()" style="width:91px;height:34px;font-size:14px; text-align:center" required>
                                <option value=""> - Day - </option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="BirthMonth" id="BirthMonth" onchange="runMonth()" style="width:91px;height:34px;font-size:14px;text-align:center" required>
                                <option value=""> - Month - </option>
                                <option value="January">January</option>
                                <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
                                <option value="March">March</option>
                                <option value="April">April</option>
                                <option value="May">May</option>
                                <option value="June">June</option>
                                <option value="July">July</option>
                                <option value="August">August</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="BirthYear" id="BirthYear" onchange="runYear()" style="width:91px; height:34px;font-size:14px; text-align:center" required>
                                <option value=""> - Year - </option>
                                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                                <option value="1989">1989</option>
                                <option value="1988">1988</option>
                                <option value="1987">1987</option>
                                <option value="1986">1986</option>
                                <option value="1985">1985</option>
                                <option value="1984">1984</option>
                                <option value="1983">1983</option>
                            </select>

                            <script>
                                function runDay() {
                                    //if (document.getElementById("srt").value != "") {
                                    var day = document.getElementById("Day").value;
                                    document.getElementById("BirthDay").value = day;
                                    //}
                                }
                            </script>

                            <script>
                                function runMonth() {
                                    //if (document.getElementById("srt").value != "") {
                                    var month = document.getElementById("BirthMonth").value;
                                    document.getElementById("BirthMonth").value = month;
                                    //}
                                }
                            </script>
                            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m., month: month, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "BirthMonth" })*@

                            <script>
                                function runYear() {
                                    //if (document.getElementById("srt").value != "") {
                                    var year = document.getElementById("Year").value;
                                    document.getElementById("BirthYear").value = year;
                                    //}
                                }
                            </script>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @*<label for="select-country" style="display:block;">Country <p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <input type="text" id="country" class="form-control" style="padding-right:25%;text-align:center;padding-left:25%;">*@
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label", @id="country"})
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Country, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>

                            <!--problem-->
                            <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

                            <script src="~/Scripts/countrySelect.min.js"></script>
                            <script>
                                $("#country").countrySelect();
                            </script>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @*<label for="username-login">Username<p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <input type="text" pattern='^(?=.{6,20}$)(?!.*[._-]{2})[a-z][a-z0-9._-]*[a-z0-9]$' title="Username needs to be between 6 to 20 characters and can only contain alphanumeric characters, _ . or - which cannot be used near each other" class="form-control"  id="username-login" required>*@
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @*<label for="mobile-login" style="text-wrap:normal">Mobile Number - So we can send you important information and reminders about your tours <p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" style="padding-right: 26.7%;" required>*@
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", id = "mobile" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @*<label for="password-login">Password <p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <input type="password"  pattern='^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!#"$%()^&*_=+-]).{8,16}$' title='Password needs to be between 8 to 20 characters and must include alphanumeric characters. Special characters accepted _ - . which must not be near each other.' class="form-control" id="password-login" required>*@
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @*<label for="confirm-password-login">Confirm Password <p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm-password-login" required>*@
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-template-main"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <div class="box" style="padding-left:14px; padding-right:14px;">
                    <h2 class="text-uppercase">Login</h2>

                    <p class="lead">Already our customer?</p>

                    <hr>

                    <form action="@Url.Action("Login","Account")" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="text">Username or Email<p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password <p style="color:red; display:inline"> *</p></label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" required>
                            <br>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("PasswordReminder","Home")"<label style="text-decoration:underline">Forgot your Password?</label></a>                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center" style="padding-top: 7px;">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-template-main"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log in</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /#content -->
```

Followed other questions however, the problem still persists.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the to put the token *inside* the form:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Register","Account")" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

You're placing it before the `form` element opens, so it's not being included in the form POST.

Comment: Thanks! You're a lifesaver :)